# Verify logs generated on datadog via katalon studio for a daily run job

Tags: selenium-webdriver, datadog, katalon-studio

We have a daily job which we run via our web application. The logs get captured on datadog and not on the console of the browser. Is there any way to integrate katalon studio with data dog or get the captured logs from data dog and verify them.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some kind of unique identifier on your logs, such as a build number or transaction id. Once you know how to find your logs, you can use the [GET Logs](https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/latest/logs/#get-a-list-of-logs) API endpoint to find all the logs that match a [search](https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/explorer/search_syntax/) for that identifier.

The other approach you could look at, though it's more advanced, is setting up [logs monitors](https://docs.datadoghq.com/monitors/types/log/#overview) to alert you when you get new logs coming in.